# How can I identify an IC marked '32D FD'?

Tags: identification, mosfet-driver, led-driver, fet, markings

I need to find the IC name of this marking number. It looks to me SOT-23 package. It is most probably an FET IC used for PWM dimming control of an LED driver. I am attaching LED driver schematic from its datasheet and also marking number of IC.

[image: marking number]

[image: Schematic of LED driver]

[Datasheet of LED driver.](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61165.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [Diodes Inc DMN6040SVTQ](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/DMN6040SVTQ.pdf) N-Channel MOSFET.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/MOSFETs_Diodes-Incorporated-DMN6040SVTQ-7_C461037.html))

Comment: can you guide me how you found that?

Comment: @ZunuranNasrullah I recognized from the markings that it's a Diodes Inc part. I've seen these 3 character device codes with the rotated 2 character date code before. Knowing that it was made by Diodes, I google searched `diodes inc "32D" marking` and found the datasheet. Also, if your question is answered, please use the checkmark to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Thanks for your answer